# How do I fetch the access token for a user using the Twitter gem and the Omniauth gem when the users is already logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Currently I authenticate the user using omniauth. This looks like this in my sessions controller and works well:

```
def create
  auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  unless @auth = Authentication.find_from_hash(auth)
    # Create a new user or add an auth to existing user, depending on
    # whether there is already a user signed in.
    @auth = Authentication.create_from_hash(auth, current_user)
  end
  # Log the authorizing user in.
  self.current_user = @auth.user

  redirect_to authentications_url, :notice => "You've signed in!"
end
```

After this, I've stored the twitter uid in my authentications table (I also use linkedin, facebook) and I *think* that the twitter sessions has been closed.

How do I now authenticate so that I can use the Twitter gem? I think it should be something like this if I was calling it right after the omniauth callback.

```
  token = auth['credentials']['token'],
  secret = auth['credentials']['secret']
  Twitter.oauth_token = token
  Twitter.oauth_token_secret = secret
```

I clearly need to restart the session and put the token and secret in the right place. How can I create a method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store both the token and the secret provided by Twitter in your authentications table (`Authentication.create_from_hash`). As long as you're doing that, this should work:

```
twitter_credentials = current_user.authorizations.find_by_provider(:twitter)

Twitter.oauth_token = twitter_credentials.token
Twitter.oauth_token_secret = twitter_credentials.token_secret
```

That's assuming that in your authentications table you store the Twitter token and secret as `token` and `token_secret`, as well as storing the provider as `twitter`

Comment: undefined method `authorizations' for #<User:0x007fd5e2081398>